# SSRS 2008 - How to hide group element when exporting to XML

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am creating a report which will be used to export to XML. I've been able to adjust the elements and attributes fairly well, with the exception of a row group that I cannot seem to get rid of. Whenever the XML is exported, the row group renders in the XML as "Details_Collection", and the elements I want are under that:

```
<Root>
 <One>
   <Details_Collection>
    <Item />
    <Item />
   </Details_Collection>
 </One>
</Root>
```

I don't want the Details_Collection element to appear at all, but I can't seem to make it go away. If I set the "DataElementOutput" to "NoOutput", then none of the child elements appear, so that doesn't work.

Is what I am trying possible, or will I need to use XSLT?

Comment: Can you just remove the details line, instead of hiding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, AFAIK *this is not possible*, the row group will always be rendered with its own element. You can give your own name for the element with the `DataElementName` property, but as you already mention in the question setting the `DataElementOutput` to `NoOutput` will hide the entire element (including child nodes).

Using [XSLT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283112%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#XSLTTransformation) is probably the easiest way to fix this, though a custom rendering extension is a heavy-weight alternative if you need even more control.

Comment: I came to that conclusion as well, thank you. Doing it through XSLT wasn't too painful, and all is working now.

Comment: Cool. Feel free to edit the answer and add your XSLT snippet, if you like. Glad you got things fixed.